# Pandas Series boxplot not showing correctly

Tags: python, pandas, plot, boxplot

I have a Pandas Series named a, and a.describe() gives this

```
count    1116.000
mean      211.495
std      1241.612
min         1.000
25%        16.000
50%        20.000
75%        57.000
max     23220.000
```

I'd like to create a boxplot out of it so I did `a.plot(kind='box')`, there is what I get：
[image]
The first few entries of the series look like this:

```
338.000
17.000
9.000
20.000
68.000
288.000
18.000
25.000
```

Why isn't the boxplot showing up correctly?

---

The maximum value indeed makes this plot unreadable. I decide to hide the outliers by doing this:

```
plt.boxplot(a, showfliers=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, regarding to your values, your box plot is showing up 'correctly' because of your max value : 23220.000. Try playing with xlim and ylim arguments of [Pandas plot function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)